# Delegated events don't work in combination with :not() selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do something on all clicks except on a certain element.

I've created a very simple example which demonstrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/nhe6wk77/.

My code:

```
$('body').on('click', ':not(a)', function () {
    // do stuff
});
```

I'd expect all click to on `<a>` to be ignored, but this is not the case.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug on jQuery's side?

Comment: Blazemonger is right, if you log `this`, you'll see that you didn't trigger the a event, but the div event, as your selector says that event is for all BUT an anchor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a lot going on in that code that's not obvious. Most importantly, the `click` event is actually attached to the `body` element. Since that element isn't an anchor, you'll always get the alert. (Event delegation works because the `click` event bubbles up from the `a` through all its ancestors, including `body`, until it reaches `document`.)

What you want to do is check the [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/). That will tell you the element that was actually clicked on, but the actual `click` event is still bound to the `body` element:

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) { // e = event object
    if ($(e.target).is(':not(a)')) {
        alert('got a click');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y3kx19z7/

Comment: Note that for `$('body').on('click', '.my-clicker', handler);` delegations, `e.target` is sometimes referencing a child you might have clicked on (i.e. a ‹span› inside the ‹a›). In that cases, it's better to use `e.currentTarget`. ([currentTarget](https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/#event-currentTarget1) vs. [target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/#event-target1))

Answer (score 7):

No this is not a bug but rather intended behaviour.

The event bubbles all the way up. By clicking the `a` node, you are still triggering it's *parents* event from the `div` node.

Read [more about event bubbling in the W3C DOM Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20030331/events.html). Just search for "bubble".

You need to stop the event propagation of the `a` nodes. i.e.:

```
$('body').on('click', ':not(a)', function () {
    // do something effectively
    alert('you should not see me when clicking a link');
});
$("a").click(function( event ) {
    // do nothing effectively, but stop event bubbling
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nhe6wk77/6/

Answer (score 5):

### It's working as intended, here's why!

Use of the `:not()` selector is honored in delegated events, but it's an uncommon practice because of how events bubble up the DOM tree potentially triggering the handler multiple times along the way.

The [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) states that:

> jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.

Notice the phrase "and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector".

In your example, jQuery is accurately not running the handler on the `a` element, but as the event bubbles up the tree, it runs the handler for any element that matches `:not(a)`, which is every other element in the path.

Here is a clear example showing how this works: http://jsfiddle.net/gfullam/5mug7p2m/

```js
$('body').on('click', ':not(a)', function (e) {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <a href="#">Click once, trigger twice</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <button type="button">Click once, trigger thrice</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Clicking on the link in the first block of nested divs, will start the event bubbling, but the clicked `a` element — a.k.a. the event `target` — doesn't trigger the handler because it doesn't match the `:not(a)` selector.

But as the event bubbles up through the DOM, each of its parents — a.k.a the event `currentTarget` — triggers the handler because they do match the `:not(a)` selector, causing the handler to run twice. Multiple triggering is something to be aware of since it may not be a desired result.

Likewise, clicking on the button in the second block of nested divs, will start the event bubbling, but this time the event `target` does match the `:not(a)` selector, so it triggers the handler immediately. Then as the event bubbles up, each of its parents matching the selector triggers the handler, too, causing the handler to run three times.

As others have suggested, you need to either bind an alternate handler that stops propagation on `a` click events or check the event `target` against the `:not(a)` selector inside your handler instead of the delegated selector.

Comment: This is the best of all the answers because it explains it in so much detail that it becomes obvious why this actually works, and how. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
    if($(e.target).is('a')){
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
    alert("woohoo!");
});
```

check the target of the click. this way you dont need to bind another event.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhe6wk77/4/)

Comment: this may apply in this case but once the link (a) should keep its default behavior (direct to some URI resource), we won't use `e.preventDefault()`.